# How to solve maximum/minimum problems using Z3 SMT-LIB online

Tags: optimization, z3

I am trying to solve some maximum/minimum problems using Z3 SMT-LIB online.

One example is:

Find two nonnegative numbers whose sum is 9 and so that the product of one number and the square of the other number is a maximum.

After many attempts the following code was constructed

```
(define-fun f ((x Real) (y Real)) Real
  (if (not (= y 0.0))
  (* y (^ x (- y 1)))
  0.0))
(declare-const x Real) 
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const z Real)
(declare-const v Real)
(simplify (* x (^ (- 9 x) 2)) :som true)
(assert (= y  (* 81.0 (f x 1))))
(assert (= z (* 18.0 (f x 2))))
(assert (= v (f x 3)))
(assert (= z (+ y  v )))
(assert (not (= x 0)))
(assert (not (= x 9)))
(set-option :pp-decimal true)
(apply (then simplify solve-eqs))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The output is:

```
(+ (* 81.0 x) (* (- 18.0) x x) (* x x x)) 
(goals 
(goal (= (* 36.0 x) (+ (* 81.0 (^ x 0.0)) (* 3.0 (^ x 2.0)))) 
(not (= x 0.0)) 
(not (= x 9.0)) 
:precision precise :depth 2) ) 

sat 
(model 
  (define-fun x () Real 3.0) 
  (define-fun v () Real 27.0) 
  (define-fun z () Real 108.0) 
  (define-fun y () Real 81.0) )
```

Run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/U1Xc)

Please let me know if you have a more efficient code for this problem.  Many thanks.

Comment: You've not explained a problem or asked a question. Please see the [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/172661). If the code is working, and you're just looking for peer review, you should delete this here and post instead to [codereview.se], which is more appropriate for that sort of question. SO is for specific questions about actual problems you're currently facing, which means there has to be an actual problem (and question) for us to help you solve.

Comment: In general, this requires the Lagrangian to be minimized, i.e. `∇L=0` with `L(x,y)=f(x,y) - lambda g(x,y)`, involving partial differentiation etc.